# Openquery with variables in datetime using like clause with linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

Everytime I execute this query I get this error: 
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator. Asking for your help. Thanks!

```
DECLARE @date datetime, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @date = '2019';

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINK2, ''SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp_users WHERE user_registered LIKE '''%' +@date+ '%''''')';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Surely you are not using the correct number of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can be varchar(4) because you are setting it as string. then use `datepart()`

```
DECLARE @date varchar(4), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @date = '2019';

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINK2, ''SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp_users WHERE DATEPART(yy, user_registered) LIKE ''''%' +@date+ '%'''''')';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: it returned this error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '%'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.