# How can I pass an int into the OPEN QUERY using a stored procedure in a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure using an  OPEN QUERY for a linked server. I am having a problem on the Where Clause.

I tried converting the where clause for the user id into varchar(10)

```
DECLARE @user_id as bigint = 32

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LMSBUILDER, 
  'SELECT       
     cc.id,cc.user_id,cc.title,cc.library_id
     ,cc.parameters,cc.filtered,cc.embed_type
     ,ll.name, ll.title as lib_title, ll.major_version
     ,ll.minor_version,ll.patch_version,ll.runnable
     ,ll.restricted,ll.fullscreen,ll.embed_types
     , ll.semantics 
   FROM 
      coursebuilder.wp_h5p_contents as cc 
      INNER JOIN coursebuilder.wp_h5p_libraries as ll 
        ON cc.library_id=ll.id 
   WHERE 
     cc.library_id IN (35,22, 34) 
     AND cc.user_id = '' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @user_id) + ''')
```

It should return all the results but instead I only got a null. Whenever I try to run it in mysql it returns values

Comment: Please fix the question (query) format and add the SQL Server (MSSQL) tag aswell.. As it looks like you are using MSSQL linked server/OPENQUERY to execute a query on MySQL..    Maybe it is also usefull to post the MySQL related tables aswell..

Comment: From the (pending) edit it is clear you try `'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @user_id) + ''` on MySQL which is invalid syntax as MySQL uses `CONCAT()` to string concatenate .. Also MySQL uses [CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) different...  Also NVARCHAR is bit different implemented in MySQL vs MSSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openquery with variables in datetime using like clause with linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722978/openquery-with-variables-in-datetime-using-like-clause-with-linked-server)

Answer (score 0):

This duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408505/dynamic-linked-server-query) is resolve your answer.

Microsoft Support [How to pass a variable to a linked server query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query) is also resolve your issue.